# After forking parent never executes

Tags: c, fork

I'm trying to get acquainted with pipes and I have written a pretty stupid parrot program that basically takes in the input from the keyboard and then displays the exact same thing:

```
if (pipe(fd) < 0) {
        perror("Pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( ( pid = fork() < 0 ) ) {
        perror("Fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( pid > 0 ) //If I'm the parent...
    {
        printf("Parent!");
        close(fd[0]);
        //as long as something is typed in and that something isn't 
        // the word "stop"
        while (((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0) && 
               (strncmp(buffer, "stop", 4) != 0))
        {
            //shove all the buffer content into the pipe
            write(fd[1], buffer, BUFFERSIZE);
        }
    }
    else //If I am the child...
    {
        printf("Child!");
        close(fd[1]);

        //as long as there's something to read
        while (pipe_read = read(fd[0], buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0)
        {
            //display on the screen!
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, pipe_read);
        }
    }
```

I get why this program doesn't get engaged in the loop, that is because the parent never executes and as a result I get `Child! Child!` as output and I can't figure out why.

Comment: If you're getting two print statements that say Child, it sounds like both processes are going into the else statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
if ( ( pid = fork() < 0 ) )
```

with

```
if ( (pid = fork()) < 0 )
```

Without the right parentheses `pid` was being set to `(fork() < 0)`, which was `0`.

Comment: +1, but there's no conversion going on. The result of `fork() < 0` *is* 0.

Comment: I forgot `c` does not have booleans!!

Comment: @blue, C has `_Bool` since 1999. The type has two values `0` and `1` and the header `stdbool.h` has two macros `false` and `true` that evaluate to these values.

Comment: @jens do comparison operators return a _Bool?

Comment: @blue, no, it is `int` but restricted to the values `0` and `1`.